# Entity framework - inserting by ID

Tags: entity-framework, bulkinsert

I'm in a situation where I'm importing lots of "link" records from an XML file, and I want to insert them in my SQL link table using Entity Framework.  My link table is literally just 2 columns, both of which are FKs and constitute the PK:

```
[UserAssessmentId] [int] NOT NULL
[AnswerId] [int] NOT NULL
```

The way I'm used to doing inserts involves the following:

1. Get the `UserAssessment` entity from the DB for `userAssessmentId`.
2. Get the `Answer` entity from the DB for `answerId`.
3. Add the `Answer` entity to the `UserAssessment` entity's `Answers` collection.
4. Repeat 2 and 3 for each `answerId` to add.
5. Call `context.SaveChanges()`.

The trouble is that this is extremely DB intensive when adding hundreds of answers; EF has to get the record for *each answer* it is adding to the link table!  I just want to insert a record with a given `userAssessmentId`, and a given `answerId`, and not go through the trouble of getting the entity first.  EF needn't worry about whether the IDs I'm inserting are valid; just assume they are.  Is there a way to get EF to do this or do I need to just use plain SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest option would probably be to create a separate context and a simple entity to represent your link table.

```
[Table("Name of the link table")]
public class UserAssessmentAnswer
{
   public int UserAssessmentId { get; set; }
   public int AnswerId { get; set; }
}

public class UserAssessmentAnswerContext : DbContext
{
   public UserAssessmentAnswerContext() 
      : base("Connection string for the real context")
   {
   }

   public IDbSet<UserAssessmentAnswer> UserAssessmentAnswers
   {
      get { return Set<UserAssessmentAnswer>(); }
   }
}
```

Then you can use the new context and entity to insert your data:

```
using (var context = new UserAssessmentAnswerContext())
{
   context.UserAssessmentAnswers.Add(new UserAssessmentAnswer
   {
      UserAssessmentId = ...,
      AnswerId = ...
   });
   ...
   context.SaveChanges();
}
```

---

**EDIT**
You'll need to turn off database initialization for the new context. In your configuration file, add:

```
<entityFramework>
   <contexts>
      <context 
         type="YourNamespace.UserAssessmentAnswerContext, YourAssembly" 
         disableDatabaseInitialization="true"
      />
   </contexts>
</entityFramework>
```

Or, you can add the following code to your startup:

```
Database.SetInitializer<UserAssessmentAnswerContext>(null);
```

Comment: +1 Sounds like a feasible solution. Probably better than incorporating the junction table in the main model (and loosing many to many).

Comment: I tried this solution, and it gives me "The model backing the 'UserAssessmentsAnswersContext' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269)." when I try to add an entity to the context.  Not sure why.

Comment: OK I just tried an `Add-Migration` on the newly-created context; it wants to drop everything, including the existing `UserAssessmentsAnswers` table (presumably because of the lack of FK references in the new context) - is there any way around this?

Comment: @Jez: You'll need to turn off database initialization for the new context.

Comment: Is there a way to disable it in code (in the constructor or something) rather than in the config file?

Comment: @Jez: Yes, you can use the `Database.SetInitializer<TContext>` method.